# Как называется обратный метод к next()? C++

Tags: c++, методы

Метод next () - возвращает указатель/итератор на следующий за каким-л элементом. Как называется обратный метод? В голову пришёл back, но как вижу, его нету. С++

Comment: `prev` называется. Заходим на https://en.cppreference.com/w/, ищем `next`. Найдя, идем в конец страницы и смотрим *See also*. Так сказать, краткая инструкция по поиску...

Comment: "Метод next()"? О чем речь? Методами в С++ обычно называются функции-члены класса. Где именно вы увидели ваш "метод next()"?

Comment: как хотите, так и назовите, лишбы назвали логичным именем.

Answer (score 1):

Очевидный ответ [`std::prev(it, n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/prev)

Менее очевидный ответ [`std::next(it, -n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next)

И для любителей классики [`std::advance(it, -n)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/advance). Отличее от предедущих в том, что эта функция не делает копию итератора, а смещает переданный.

А вообще, раз уж взялись работать с итераторами, просмотрите содержимое библиотеки [iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/iterator), чтоб не гадать